# How to set to always be a minimal distance at the paragraph endings from the right margin at twocolumn environment?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

How to insert 5 mm automatically, just in case the end of the paragraph reached the right margin (if it didn't reach the margin anyway, nothing would happen) for example:

```
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.| < The paragraph ending and the right margin
```

and after the change:

```
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah |


Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah  Bl- |

ah.     | < Automatically inserts 5 mm

Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah |
(The next paragraph reaches the margin because it is not over yet)

(And if there were, say, 15 mm to the right margin, let nothing happen, hold the 15 mm, do not insert another 5 mm)
```

Answer (score 4):

The space at the end of a paragraph is `\parfillskip` so you want

```
\setlength\parfillskip{5mm plus 1\fill}
```

for a length with a mininmum length of 5mm

Note that if you have an unbreakable word (or boxed construct) at the end of the paragraph that has size within 5mm of `\columnwidth` this will not shrink so will force an extra all-white line to hold the final space. So you might want instead

```
\setlength\parfillskip{5mm plus 1\fill minus 5pt}
```

so it can shrink in an emergency